# Convert dictionary timestamp key-value pairs into datetime

Tags: python, dictionary, datetime, python-datetime

I have a dictionary which has a timestamp stored as key and value pairs:

```py
timestamp_info = {
    'day': 8, 'fold': 0, 'hour': 0,
    'max': {'day': 31, 'fold': 0,'hour': 23},
    'microsecond': 639000, 'minute': 17, 'month': 10, 'second': 35, 'year': 2021
}
```

I am trying to take timestamp from dictionary and convert to `datetime.datetime` timestamp format. I tried the following but it does not work as it asks for `str` (exact error is: "strptime() argument 1 must be str, not dict"):

```
result = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp_info, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I want this result to be compared with `datetime.datetime.now` and take difference in seconds between current timestamp and result, that is the reason I need timestamp format.

Comment: What do you mean that "it does not work as it asks for `str`"? What is the exact error message? And what should the value of `result` be? What datetime should it represent? Please [edit] your question to include these details.

Comment: I guess datetime.datetime.strtime takes as a first argument as string and I have a dictionary for timestamp, exact error is : strptime() argument 1 must be str, not dict

Comment: Yes, that is true. You should still include the entire error message in your question rather than summarize it. Also, I edited my previous comment asking for a few other details in case you missed it. You may need to refresh the page to see the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chirs Oram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69498639/1440565) already shows how to build a string that you can then parse with `strptime()`. Alternatively, you can pass the values directly to `datetime()`:

```
timestamp_info = {
    'day':8, 'fold':0,'hour':0, 'max':{'day':31, 'fold':0,'hour':23},
    'microsecond':639000,'minute':17,'month':10,'second':35, 'year':2021
}

year = timestamp_info['year']
month = timestamp_info['month']
day = timestamp_info['day']
hour = timestamp_info['hour']
minute = timestamp_info['minute']
second = timestamp_info['second']

result = datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=hour, minute=minute, second=second)
```

Or you can do this more succinctly by removing the attributes not needed for datetime:

```
timestamp_info = {
    'day':8, 'fold':0,'hour':0, 'max':{'day':31, 'fold':0,'hour':23},
    'microsecond':639000,'minute':17,'month':10,'second':35, 'year':2021
}

del timestamp_info['fold']
del timestamp_info['max']

result = datetime.datetime(**timestamp_info)
```

Comment: for the second code can we track till microseconds? when I tried by microsecond = ```str(timestamp_info['microsecond'])
timestamp = '-'.join([year, month, day]) + ' ' + ':'.join([hour, minute, second])+ '.'.join([microsecond]) ``` it shows error
``` time data '2021-10-8 0:17:35639000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'```  I tried with second solution and it works better.

Comment: @user14806829 Look closely at the string that you are trying to parse. Do you see what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract each part of the timestamp in the specified format, and concatenate them into a string:

```py
timestamp_info = {
    'day':8, 'fold':0,'hour':0, 'max':{'day':31, 'fold':0,'hour':23},
    'microsecond':639000,'minute':17,'month':10,'second':35, 'year':2021
}

year = str(timestamp_info['year'])
month = str(timestamp_info['month'])
day = str(timestamp_info['day'])
hour = str(timestamp_info['hour'])
minute = str(timestamp_info['minute'])
second = str(timestamp_info['second'])
timestamp = '-'.join([year, month, day]) + ' ' + ':'.join([hour, minute, second])

result = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Which results in:

```
2021-10-08 00:17:35
```

Comment: While it might work, it is completely unnecessary to build a string only to have it parsed again, as the values can be passed directly to the `datetime.datetime` constructor.

Comment: True, should avoid this if there is another way. Code-Apprentice's answer is more succinct.